# Middle mouse button not working on Debian 11 stable

Tags: debian, hardware, mouse

I've been using Debian 11 Bullseye Stable for about a year now, and I just noticed that my middle mouse click isn't working. I only discovered this by playing a game where the middle-mouse click is used for rotating the camera and there's no response, although the scroll wheel does work. I've read that a lot of Linux distros will use the middle mouse button for copy-paste in the terminal, but this isn't working for me either. I'm using GNOME and GNOME tweaks has an option for 'Middle Click Paste', but that doesn't seem to help. I'm fairly certain I'm using Wayland, so a lot of the solutions online that involve X11 don't seem to work.

The device is present in **lsusb**:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c08f Logitech, Inc. G403 HERO Gaming Mouse
```

But otherwise I'm not sure where to look or what to try.

EDIT: I was able to use input-remapper 1.5.1 to map one of the left mouse buttons to the middle mouse button, and then that button performs the typical linux "paste the selection" action in the terminal. Also I found this, indicating that it may be an issue with the version of XWayland in Debian 11: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/issues/1130